# Why custom validator validate twice SpringMvc

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I found the following:

1. If a class is marked as `@Validated`, then an entity, at least one field of which is marked with my custom annotation `@Unique`, will be checked twice. Moreover, the first time the validator will have a context and a service, but the second time everything is null. It seems to me that because of `@Validated` the entity is checked twice, but I don’t understand why, and even why without the injected context and service?
2. If the class is not marked, the entity is validated fine, even with my custom annotation. But parameter validation does not work, for example `public String someFunction (@RequestParam ("email") @Email String email)` and if send something wrong nothing happened.

My custom validator

```
public class UniqueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Unique, Object> {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Autowired
private FieldValueExists service;
private String fieldName;

@Override
public void initialize(Unique unique) {

    Class<? extends FieldValueExists> clazz = unique.service();
    this.fieldName = unique.fieldName();
    String serviceQualifier = unique.serviceQualifier();

    if (!serviceQualifier.equals("")) {
        this.service = this.applicationContext.getBean(serviceQualifier, clazz);
    } else {
        this.service = this.applicationContext.getBean(clazz);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Object o, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    return !this.service.fieldValueExists(o, this.fieldName);
}
}
```

Annotation

```
@Target(FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueValidator.class)
public @interface Unique {
    String message() default "Field is not unique";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    Class<? extends FieldValueExists> service() default FieldValueExists.class;
    String serviceQualifier() default "";
    String fieldName();
}
```

Part of my dto which have to be validated

```
@JsonRootName("userCreate")
public class UserModelCreateDto {

@Size(min = 4, max = 32)
@NotBlank
@Unique(fieldName = "login", serviceQualifier = "userServiceImpl")
private String login;
```

And controller

```
 @RestController
 @Validated
 public class AuthenticationController {

     private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationController.class);

     @Autowired
     private UserService userService;

     @Autowired
     private ModelMapper modelMapper;


     @PostMapping("/sign-up")
     @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
     public UserModelDto saveUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserModelCreateDto userModelCreateDto, BindingResult result) {
         if (result.hasErrors()) {
             throw new ValidationException(getValidationErrorsAsString(result));
         } else {
             UserModelDto user = userService.save(userModelCreateDto);
             LOG.info("User #" + user.getId() + " has been create account");
             return user;
         }
     }
```

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it's the bug of spring. Parameters annotated with `@Validated` or `@Valid` will be validated once more in `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver#validateIfApplicable` other than normal validation in `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor#invoke`.